# I have a javascript carousel for images and youtube video, but it breaks after playing one video. What part of the functions are causing this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple functions that are being used to create a carousel to  view youtube videos, but when I add more than one video in the carousel it will disappear entirely or it will disappear after clicking one the next buttons. I am very new to javascript and do not understand where in the functions it is creating that behavior. In the example below it is three images then a video. When I run that way it is fine. However if you change the video to where one of the images are located it will get the video and when you click the next button the whole carousel will disappear, if you put the video in the first image location it will not load at all. I am a video located where each img is located within the html.

```
    <div class="container">

          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item ">
                <div class="carousel-video-inner">
                  <div class="d-block w-100" id="video-player" data-video-id="S3vJfLAPQAg"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>


    $(function() {
      $(".carousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
        var prev = $(this)
          .find(".active")
          .index();
        var next = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
        var video = $("#video-player")[0];
        var videoSlide = $("#video-player")
          .closest(".carousel-item")
          .index();
        if (next === videoSlide) {
          if (video.tagName == "IFRAME") {
            player.playVideo();
          } else {
            createVideo(video);
          }
        } else {
          if (typeof player !== "undefined") {
            player.pauseVideo();
          }
        }
      });
    });

function createVideo(video) {
  var youtubeScriptId = "youtube-api";
  var youtubeScript = document.getElementById(youtubeScriptId);
  var videoId = video.getAttribute("data-video-id");

  if (youtubeScript === null) {
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    tag.id = youtubeScriptId;
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScript);
  }

  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    window.player = new window.YT.Player(video, {
      videoId: videoId,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        modestbranding: 1,
        rel: 0
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Expected result when replacing the images with:

```
<div class="carousel-video-inner">
              <div class="d-block w-100" id="video-player" data-video-id="S3vJfLAPQAg"></div>
```

would be that it is now a carousel with 4 youtube video's that you can scroll through.
Actual results:
Entire carousel disappears or after playing the first youtube movie it disappears.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? You can inspect the console by opening up the developer tools in chrome https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: Hi Brandon R, I  did get this error: www-widgetapi.js:154 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://test.com').